# Netify-gatsby form submission not working with custom Success Component

Tags: reactjs, forms, gatsby, netlify

I am using Netify-form with gatsby JS. I am trying to show a success alert Component when a user submits the form. This is working fine, but I am not able to get form data under my Netify account.

```
handleSubmit = (e) => {
    this.setState({showSuccessMsg: true});
    e.preventDefault();
};

<form name="subscribe"
       method="POST"
       onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}  // custom handler 
       action=""
       data-netlify="true"
       data-netlify-honeypot="bot-field"
       className="form-inline d-flex">
       <input type="hidden" name="form-name" value="subscribe"/>
       <input type="hidden" name="bot-field"/>
           .....
           .....

     <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary mx-auto">
         Subscribe
     </button>
</form>

<div>
    {this.state.showSuccessMsg ? <SuccessAlert/> : ''}
</div>
```

PS: commenting this `// onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}`, I am able to get data but I am loosing showing success alert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Netlify forms setup - Success messages](https://docs.netlify.com/forms/setup/#success-messages)

> By default, when visitors complete a form, they will see a generically styled success message with a link back to the form page. You can replace the default success message with a custom page you create by adding an action attribute to the  tag, entering the path of your custom page (like "/pages/success") as the value. The path must be relative to the site root, starting with a /.

Or you could check out this guide from [Netlify - How to Integrate Netlify’s Form Handling in a React App](https://www.netlify.com/blog/2017/07/20/how-to-integrate-netlifys-form-handling-in-a-react-app) which has a gatsby specific example for submitting with js.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'

function encode(data) {
  return Object.keys(data)
    .map((key) => encodeURIComponent(key) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(data[key]))
    .join('&')
}

export default function Contact() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({})

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setState({ ...state, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
  }

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const form = e.target
    fetch('/', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
      body: encode({
        'form-name': form.getAttribute('name'),
        ...state,
      }),
    })
    .then(() => alert('success')))
    .catch((error) => alert(error))
  }

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Contact</h1>
      <form
        name="contact"
        method="post"
        action="/thanks/"
        data-netlify="true"
        data-netlify-honeypot="bot-field"
        onSubmit={handleSubmit}
      >
        {/* The `form-name` hidden field is required to support form submissions without JavaScript */}
        <input type="hidden" name="form-name" value="contact" />
        <div hidden>
          <label>
            Don’t fill this out: <input name="bot-field" onChange={handleChange} />
          </label>
        </div>
        <label>
        Your name:
        <input type="text" name="name" onChange={handleChange} />
        </label>
        <label>
        Your email:
        <input type="email" name="email" onChange={handleChange} />
        </label>
        <label>
        Message:
        <textarea name="message" onChange={handleChange} />
        </label>
        <button type="submit">Send</button>
      </form>
    </>
  )
}
```